# Set time to live in Azure Blob containers created using BlobServiceClient

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

I'm currently using the following setup to create containers in an Azure Storage Account, and writing blobs to those containers:

```py
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

connstr = "..."
bsc = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connstr)
container_client = bsc.create_container(name="some_container")
blob_client = container_client.upload_blob("some_blob", data="data_item", metadata={})
```

but nowhere in this flow can I find a way to set a time to live (TTL, or maximum lifecycle time) for these blobs or containers.

From what I've understood you can create rules for the storage account using [blob storage lifecycle management rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/lifecycle-management-overview?tabs=azure-portal), but this would complicate the script significantly. I'd ideally like to be able to set a different blob-TTL for each container. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with a combination of the suggestion from @dasari-kamali and other sources. My solution was that I defined a number of standardized rules in the Lifecycle-Management section of my Storage Account:

[image]

Here I have specific rules for 1 day, 7 days, etc. Each of the specific rules have key/value filters which determine which blobs they apply to. Here for example is the filter value for "specificTtl3":

[image]

Then you can use the blob tag values (`TTL-in-days=7`) to determine which rule they should follow. I additionally have a global blob deletion rule which defines a max for all blobs (without tag filtering).

This workaround isn't perfect as you need to have predetermined rules in place (meaning you can't dynamically set them to a value that isn't configured), but it works nicely for my application. This way you also avoid having a timed function run at regular intervals.

Answer (score 0):

**Below is the Python code snippet for Setting TTL Property in Azure Blob Object :**

**Code**:-

```py
import time
from datetime import datetime
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

#Code - Initialize Connection String of Azure Storage and Container name using python
blob_client = container_client.upload_blob("sampleblob.txt", data="data_item", metadata={"expiration_time": "2023-05-15T13:54:21Z"})  

def check_and_enforce_ttl(container_client):

    blobs = container_client.list_blobs()
    current_time = int(time.time())

    for blob in blobs:
        blob_properties = blob_client.get_blob_properties()
        metadata = blob_properties.metadata

        ttl = metadata.get("ttl")
        if ttl is not None:
            ttl_seconds = int(ttl)

            creation_time_timestamp = int(blob_properties.creation_time.timestamp())
            delete_time = creation_time_timestamp + ttl_seconds

            if current_time >= delete_time:
                blob_client.delete_blob()
                print(f"Blob '{blob.name}' has expired and has been deleted.")
            else:
                pass
    check_and_enforce_ttl(container_client)
```

***Output:-***

[image]

For initializing the Azure Blob Storage Connection String and retrieving the blob metadata information using Python Code, refer to this MS  [Doc1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.containerclient?view=azure-python)  &  [Doc2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-properties-metadata-python#set-and-retrieve-metadata).